# Python Azure SDK: get Key Vault referenced value from App Configuration service

Tags: python, azure, reference, azure-keyvault, azure-app-configuration

I would like to retrieve Azure Key Vault referenced secrets in App Configuration service.
In dotnet it is a piece of cake, you simply add options.ConfigureKeyVault and can retrieve secret like this:

```cs
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddAzureAppConfiguration(options => {
        options.Connect(
            new Uri("https://app-cf.azconfig.io"), credential
        ).Select("*", "label");
        options.ConfigureKeyVault(kv => {
            kv.SetCredential(credential);
        });
    }).Build();
    var test = config.GetValue<string>("secret_name");
```

But in Python I haven't found any method to add KeyVault handling in AzureAppConfigurationClient, and when you try to retrieve Key Vault referenced secret you simply get string:

`'{"uri":"https://kv-name.vault.azure.net/secrets/SecretName"}'`.

I've "solved" this writing function:

```py
import json
from pathlib import Path
from azure.appconfiguration import AzureAppConfigurationClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient

def get_appcf_label(base_url: str, label: str) -> dict:
    """Get app configurations for specified label."""
    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    client = AzureAppConfigurationClient(base_url, credential)
    filtered_listed = client.list_configuration_settings(
        key_filter="*", label_filter=label
    )
    config = dict()
    for item in filtered_listed:
        if (
            item.content_type
            == "application/vnd.microsoft.appconfig.keyvaultref+json;charset=utf-8"
        ):
            url_parts = Path(json.loads(item.value)["uri"]).parts
            vault_url = "//".join(url_parts[:2])
            kv_secret = url_parts[-1]
            kv_client = SecretClient(vault_url, credential)
            secret_val = kv_client.get_secret(kv_secret).value
            config.update({item.key: secret_val})
        else:
            config.update({item.key: item.value})
    return config
```

I don't like this solution, especially string parsing, even though it's working, but I cannot figure out a better way to do it. Do you have any ideas how to do it in a smarter/cleaner way?

Comment: Do you have any concerns about this issue?

Comment: @Szymon Osiecki Were you able to find any better solution using the SDK itself.?

Answer (score 0):

## You can get value by rest api.

*I think this should be the easiest way. In addition, you should consult the information to obtain the `Bearer token`.*

**[RESR API --Web Apps - Get App Setting Key Vault Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/getappsettingkeyvaultreference#code-try-0)**

You can use `import requests` in your code. Below post can show you how to send post request.

[Using API microsoft translator in a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64216764/using-api-microsoft-translator-in-a-python-script/64273114#64273114)

Answer (score 0):

It seems even azure cli does the same, if you need keyvault secret resolve, then it creates a keyvault client.
Relevant code from azure cli:
`/opt/az/lib/python3.11/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/appconfig/keyvalue.py`

```
    # fetch key values from user's configstore
    src_kvs = __read_kv_from_config_store(azconfig_client,
                                          key=key,
                                          label=label if label else SearchFilterOptions.EMPTY_LABEL,
                                          prefix_to_remove=prefix if not export_as_reference else "",
                                          snapshot=snapshot,
                                          cli_ctx=cmd.cli_ctx if resolve_keyvault else None)
```

and the relevant block from `_kv_helpers.py`

```
    if cli_ctx:
        from azure.cli.command_modules.keyvault._client_factory import keyvault_data_plane_factory
        keyvault_client = keyvault_data_plane_factory(cli_ctx)
```