# How to identify speaker using python sdk in using Azure cognitive speech translation API?

Tags: python, azure, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, speech

I am trying to use modified event based synthesis code sample provided on azure documentation for speech to speech translation. However, during the process, I am also want to identify speakers (speaker1, speaker2) but I don't see an function in Python SDK which will help me in identifying the speakers as a part of speech=to-text translation. Can someone suggest ways to identify speaker during speech-to-text translaion? Below is the code snippet:

```
def translate_speech_to_text():

    translation_config = speechsdk.translation.SpeechTranslationConfig(subscription=speech_key, region=service_region)
    translation_config.speech_recognition_language = from_language
    translation_config.add_target_language(to_language)
    translation_config.voice_name = "en-GB-Susan"

    translation_config.request_word_level_timestamps()
    translation_config.output_format = speechsdk.OutputFormat(0)

    audio_input = speechsdk.AudioConfig(filename=filename)
    recognizer = speechsdk.translation.TranslationRecognizer(translation_config = translation_config, audio_config = audio_input)

    done = False

    def stop_cb(evt):
        """callback that stops continuous recognition upon receiving an event `evt`"""
        #print('CLOSING on {}'.format(evt))
        recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition()
        nonlocal done
        done = True

    all_results = []
    def handle_final_result(evt):
        #all_results.append(evt.result.text)
        #all_results.append(evt.result.translations['en'])
        all_results.append(evt.result.json)
    
    recognizer.recognized.connect(handle_final_result)
    # Connect callbacks to the events fired by the speech recognizer
    recognizer.recognizing.connect(lambda evt: print('RECOGNIZING: {}'.format(evt)))
    recognizer.recognized.connect(lambda evt: print('RECOGNIZED: {}'.format(evt)))
    recognizer.session_started.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STARTED: {}'.format(evt)))
    recognizer.session_stopped.connect(lambda evt: print('SESSION STOPPED {}'.format(evt)))
    #recognizer.canceled.connect(lambda evt: print('CANCELED {}'.format(evt)))
    recognizer.session_stopped.connect(stop_cb)
    recognizer.canceled.connect(stop_cb)
    
    def synthesis_callback(evt):
        print('Audio: {}'.format(len(evt.result.audio)))
        print('Reason: {}'.format(evt.result.reason))
        with open('out.wav', 'wb') as wavfile:
            wavfile.write(evt.result.audio)
   
    recognizer.synthesizing.connect(synthesis_callback)
    recognizer.start_continuous_recognition()    

    while not done:
        time.sleep(.5)
    
    print("Printing all results:")
    print(all_results)

translate_speech_to_text()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to identify speaker, you should use `Speech Service`.

## Recommend to use REST API.

[Text Independent - Identify Single Speaker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/speakerrecognition/identification/textindependent/identifysinglespeaker)

`Speech Services` has a complete SDK in `C#`, `C++`, `JavaScript`, `REST`, and can perform `Speaker Recognition`. (I searched the `Python SDK`, but I haven’t found a method that can be used directly to identify it.)

## Suggestion

**[1. It is recommended to read the Speech related documents carefully and how to use this service.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-speaker-recognition?tabs=script&pivots=programming-language-curl)**

**[2. It is recommended to use request to send http post requests.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64216764/using-api-microsoft-translator-in-a-python-script/64273114#64273114)**

Comment: Thanks. Yes, even I had seen that. So I assume, currently it is not possible to do speaker identification using Python SDK.

Comment: @HarshadPatil SpeakerRecognizer is not yet available for Speech SDK for Python, we will be adding it in the future releases.